# How can I add an audioclip in Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to add a sound once a button is clicked and it doesn't seem to be working. I've been trying different approaches and this seems to be the closest thing to work except for this one error message. I'm open to any suggestions.

```
package beatbox;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;


 public class BeatBox extends Application {
 // Adding audio clip
 private static final AudioClip clip1 = new AudioClip(AudioPlayer.class.getResource("http://www.wavlist.com/soundfx/029/piano2.wav").toString());

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    // Create gridpane for button display
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    Button btn1 = new Button("");
    gridPane.add(btn1, 0, 0, 1, 1);

    // Playing sound and changing color on button click
    btn1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            clip1.play();
            btn1.setStyle(" -fx-base: #99ccff;");
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 302, 335);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

(UPDATE)
here's the exception

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplicationWithArgs$156(LauncherImpl.java:352)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at beatbox.BeatBox.<clinit>(BeatBox.java:24)
```

Comment: You just need `clip1.play();` not `AudioPlayer.clip1.play();` I'm not sure how you expected that line of code to work. "_it also gives me an error message telling me that AudioPlayer is an internal API but I'm not sure what that means_" It's not an error, just a warning and it is pretty clear right there in the console, it means it may be removed in the future.

Comment: sorry.. I'm still a beginner. Anyways, I still got an exception after using your suggestion.

Comment: "_I still got an exception_" Well we can't help you if you don't tell us what the new exception is and show us your updated code...

Comment: I just updated the original question @csm_dev

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at beatbox.BeatBox.<clinit>(BeatBox.java:24)` Which line is #24 in BeatBox.java? My guess is it is the line where you instantiate your `AudioClip`. Seems `AudioPlayer.class.getResource("http://www.wavlist.com/soundfx/029/piano2.wav")` did not return what you expected.

Comment: private static final AudioClip clip1 = new AudioClip(AudioPlayer.class.getResource("http://www.wavlist.com/soundfx/029/piano2.wav").toString()); @csm_dev

Comment: I think `getResource` is trying to get a file from inside your project - if you want to get something from the web you need to download it. To be sure, you can separate that chain of method calls onto separate lines of code and debug each one.

Comment: is there a way to do this using a url? I'm not sure how to add it to my source folder @csm_dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, first, please close the main method with curly brace "}" to get rid of syntax error. Second, remove the import:

```
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
```

and import this:

```
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;
```

Third, remove the AudioPlayer.class.getResource().toString and just use the url.

```
private static final AudioClip clip1 = new AudioClip("http://www.wavlist.com/soundfx/029/piano2.wav");
```

That's it. Audio plays!